# How to set up an UIButton?

Tags: iphone

I'd like to know how to set up an `UIButton`. I figured the `buttonType` method, still, I don't know the method for using `CGRectMake()` on it.

Also here is a separate doubt: Can I assign a different method `@selector` for the same `button` on different methods?

Thanks.

Comment: if you accept some of your answers to previous questions more people will answer your question

Comment: Hey. Well, I was wrong not to accept people's answers, but saying people would be idiots to answer this question is something that I don't agree with. How is this a community of developers if all they want is to get votes?

Comment: It's not about 'them', it's about You, how grateful are you to them, they who have given two most precious things of those, 1st Knowledge 2nd Time. So it's better to accept(if you got helped), I'm glad you did so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to set it up in a xib file.

If you want to create it manually, use `+buttonWithType:` as you suggest, set its frame like

```
// CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,100,20)
```

Set its title with

```
myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Title!";
```

To set the selector, use

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Finally, add it from your view controller with

```
[self.view addSubview:myButton]
```

The selector's method might look like

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)target
{
    NSLog(@"Button clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could get the button by type from iOS framework.

```
 UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 myButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,heigth);
```

you can set the action: method for an button using `addTarget:` method, you could use it any mumber of time and each time it will override the previously assigned action method.

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickedButtonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and implement the `ClickedButtonAction:` method.

```
-(void) ClickedButtonAction:(id) sender
{

}
```